# How do you write a system test for your runtime?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, system-testing, polkadot

Hi I am developing a runtime using Substrate-FRAME and I would like to know how can I write a system test for my runtime?

The main purpose of writing a system test is to ensure that the final build is fulfilling all of the required specifications and also to ensure nothing is compromised on a runtime upgrade.
The idea for me is something similar to point no. 2 mentioned in [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/3479#issuecomment-524769603) thread.

Any documentation regarding this type of tests would be greatly helpful.

**Update:**

I ended up using `py-substrate-interface` to make test scenarios. Now I can automatically deploy nodes to form a network (thanks to Python) and run my custom system test scenarios. Very useful tool for developing runtimes in Substrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overview [here on the DevHub](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/runtime/tests#docsNav)

And there are examples [throughout substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) that include `tests.rs` and `mock.rs` files to use as reference.

If you have not already, checkout the [create a pallet tutorial](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-a-pallet/) and the [recipes](https://substrate.dev/recipes/) all have some *tasty* examples to look at for these as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response @NukeManDan.
But it seems that the tests you are referring to (`mock.rs` and `tests.rs`) look like unit/integration tests. I was referring to something more like system test suite which checks the expected behavior of a runtime.

Comment: There are a few tools in https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate that might be of interest, but I am not aware of any specific full testing suite available for generic substrate chains. The allowed customizations on your runtime are _near infinite_ , so I wouldn't expect such a tool without needing heavy customizations needed anyhow.

Comment: `node/executor/tests` is probably the closest to what you want, from the included [node in substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node/executor/tests)

Comment: OK I see why it is difficult to have a full testing suite for substrate based chains. I'll look into `node/executor/tests` and try to come up with something. Thanks a lot I'll mark this as answered.